# How to remove a single remote from a LiftMaster garage door opener?

Tags: garage-door-opener, remote-control

I have a garage door with a red auto-learn button that is used by several people. I would like to remove a single programmed remote from the opener without deprogramming all the other remotes that are currently in use. Is there a way to deprogram a single remote? Can I reset the remote itself back to factory default?

When I search, all I can find is instructions on resetting the garage door opener itself by pressing and holding the learn button until all the programmed remotes are deprogrammed, but that requires everyone to reprogram their remotes. I would like to avoid this.

The remotes are GD-R12 three button Generics design to replace 973LM by liftmaster.

Comment: Liftmaster does not provide instructions for doing this, you have probably already searched their website. As they are the authority on their systems and we are not, asking here is redundant. VtC

Comment: I don’t see a reason for a down vote. There are tricks out there sometimes but not in this case.

Comment: It seems like there would be a way to erase the memory in the remote itself so it loses its sync with any receiver.

Comment: If say the remote you want to remove belongs to someone else and you let them program it to your garage, you could go with them to their garage and reprogram your button with their opener.  I haven't seen a remote with a factory reset button so that would be the only way.  Well, you could "reprogram" it destructively with a hammer ... I did that with a remote that was becoming flakey, before throwing it away.

Comment: IDK if maybe your actual need might be not quite what you are asking.   My remotes all have button "C" programmed to my MIL's house.   If I sell my house, I will not "deprogram" my MIL's opener from my remotes.   I will REPROGRAM all my button Cs to my own opener.  Maybe that helps?

Comment: I live in a condo with a shared gate a personal garage door. one example: I accidentally programmed a remote to open both gate and garage door simultaneously. I don't want that. If I reset the gate codes. Everyone in the association will have their remotes deprogrammed. That's a big problem. I don't understand why this is so difficult. I can't clear the memory of the remote?

Comment: Because the remote doesn't have "memory" in that sense. It has some for the rolling codes used in newer systems (since ~2000 or so), but the _remote_ doesn't remember the _opener_, it's the _opener_ that remembers the _remote_. In your situation, I would suggest that you reset the garage door, then reprogram it with all the remotes/buttons that need to open it, leaving the communal gate alone. _You_ may have one remote with the "wrong" button opening the gate, but you'll get used to it quickly without annoying everyone else in the condos.

Comment: Since, however, this is likely a _commercial_ system to open the condo gate, there may be a way to get it to "forget" a specific remote. However, without exact details on the make/model, there's no way for any of us to search the internet for you. Your best bet, anyway, is to call Liftmaster and ask them. BTW - the first thing they'll ask for is the model #, and possibly even the serial # of the unit in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can remove one.

Steps:

1. Grab remote that you want to remove.
2. Take out batteries (if there are any).
3. Sit remote on driveway.
4. Beat it with a hammer.
5. Test remote and make sure it doesn't work!

Comment: @FreeMan - It's actually the easiest way.  The remotes are $8.   So if you decide you don't need one anymore and don't want it getting in wrong hands you destroy like you would an unused credit card.

Comment: this is not helpful.

Comment: "Not helpful" opines the OP, yet it has the check mark. Go figure...

Comment: @FreeMan - sums up half my answers.

Answer (score 8):

They all have to be reprogrammed.

When you teach the system you add remotes 1 by 1.

To remove 1, all remotes are erased from memory.
they have to be taught 1 by 1 again sorry.

Comment: I had the old pin setting ones.   I miss those and I heard they were actually more secure.

Comment: This has been my experience too..... all  or nothing.+1

Comment: @DMoore, the old ones with dip-switches (pins) were not more secure.  The best ones I had seen had 12 switches which gives only 4096 combinations.  New ones are more sophisticated.

Comment: but how do you remove just 1 :)